# How to cleanly test and truncate string properties

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public void EnsureFieldLengths(SubmissionRequest request)
{
    TestAndTruncate(request?.ApplicationSubmission?.Applicant?.Address?.Line1, 60);
}

public void TestAndTruncate(string field, int maxLength)
{
    if(field != null)
    {
        field = field.Left(maxLength);
    }
}
```

`Left()` is an extension method off string to do the truncation.  The above obviously doesn't work, as the property is not passed by `ref` and thus setting `field` doesn't make it back to the actual property.

I'm fully aware how to resolve this doing something like

```
if(longProperty != null)
{
    longProperty = longProperty.Left(60);
}
```

However, I'm curious if I can solve this in a more readable manner, having to only type out `longProperty` once.  I have 20-30 of these fields, and it would make it more readable to have a one-liner.  I thought a `ref` parameter would work, but properties cannot be passed as `ref`.

Again, there is no problem doing the 'long hand' implementation of this, I'm just interested to see if someone smarter than me knows of a way to do this, without using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the cleanest option might be to use C#9 pattern matching:

```
if (request?.ApplicationSubmission?.Applicant?.Address is { Line1: { Length: > 60 } line1 } address)
{
    address.Line1 = line1.Substring(0, 60);
}
```

Or, if you need to process multiple properties on the address:

```
if (request?.ApplicationSubmission?.Applicant?.Address is {} address)
{
    if (address.Line1 is { Length: > 60 } line1)
    {
        address.Line1 = line1.Substring(0, 60);
    }
    if (address.Line2 is { Length: > 60 } line2)
    {
        address.Line2 = line2.Substring(0, 60);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hah! Cool.  I've done a bit of the pattern matching but this kicks it up a notch.  Thanks!